# Apache spark - Dataset write method not working as expected for postgresql database

Tags: java, postgresql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to write my spark dataset to postgresql existing table. I am using dataset write method with append mode. While using i am getting exception like table already exists. It's strange, I already gave Append mode. When i change options to sqlserver/oracle it is working with out exception.

Spark Version: I executed in both 2.1.0 and 2.2.1
PostgreSQL: 9.5.6
JDBC Driver: I used old one(9.4-1201-jdbc41) and latest (2.0.0)

Database Properties:

```
destinationProps.put("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver");
destinationProps.put("url", "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:30001/dbmig");
destinationProps.put("user", "dbmig");
destinationProps.put("password", "dbmig");
```

Dataset Write Code:

```
valueAnalysisDataset.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(destinationDbMap.get("url"), "dqvalue", destinationdbProperties);
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "dqvalue" already exists
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2412)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2125)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:297)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:354)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:301)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:287)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:264)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeUpdate(PgStatement.java:244)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.createTable(JdbcUtils.scala:806)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:469)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:609)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc(DataFrameWriter.scala:460)
    at com.ads.dqam.action.impl.PostgresValueAnalysis.persistValueAnalysis(PostgresValueAnalysis.java:25)
    at com.ads.dqam.action.AbstractValueAnalysis.persistAnalysis(AbstractValueAnalysis.java:81)
    at com.ads.dqam.Analysis.doAnalysis(Analysis.java:32)
    at com.ads.dqam.Client.main(Client.java:71)
```

[image: Console output for exception and postgresql query execution]

Comment: Thank you for fixing the issues. I also recommend [How to make good reproducible Apache Spark Dataframe examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48427185/8371915)